# conditional preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a main array **main('Quality','Effectiveness','Effectiveness','Quality','Quality','Quality'**)
and an array with unique values 
**unique('Quality','Effectiveness')**

depending on the occurrence of the element of unique array in the main array, i want to append an integer to the value in main array i know it is possible in perl in a simple way..

```
foreach $uni(@unique){
     foreach $val(@main){
          $i = 1;
         if($val eq $uni){
             $val =~ s/(.*)/$1\_$i/;
              $i ++;
         }
     }
 }
```

now what i am expecting as output is main

> ('Quality_1','Effectiveness_1','Effectiveness_2','Quality_2','Quality_3')

I am trying to replace the value in main with the integer appended as i want to maintain the order as in main array.

Can you please help me do the same in php.
Here is my incomplete code in php :

```
 foreach($uni_arr as $value){
foreach($type_of_metric_main as $metric){
if($metric == $value){
    $metric = preg_replace("(.*)","$match[1]_$i",$metric);
            // Need help here
}
  }
```

Comment: There is no point in using a regex here.

Comment: Seems like you're missing the `$i` and the code to increment it.

Comment: guys.. in perl if use the substitute regex, the value gets updated in the parent array..

the main array will have the values updated with the integer suffix

Comment: @ShreyasGowda: `$match[1]` is ambiguous, and not declared, the replacement should be `"$1_$i"`. Also check my answer: Perl isn't PHP, so your approach might not be ideal. That, and the original array won't be updated with your code: `foreach` assigns copies, not references. Changing a copy does nothing to the original

Comment: php syntax is very different compared to perl.. i was just trying to find out if we could use $1 directly instead of $match[1]..

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, although Perl is said to be based on the principle of *"TMTOWTDI"*, the language tends to develop a preference to solve things with Regex. In this case, I wouldn't, though.
Also `"$matches[1]"` is ambiguous. Do you want PHP to interpret `$matches` as the var, or `$matches[1]`? It doesn't know. when using arrays inside double quotes, you should, therefore use curly braces for clarity: `"{$matches[1]}_$i"`. That said, `preg_*` functions don't create a `$matches` array, but regular back-refrences. What you meant, then was `"$1_$i"`. But that's besides the point, below is a more performant approach (no regex, no nested loops):

It's not that hard in PHP, either. What's more, it doesn't even require a nested loop.

```
$main = array('Quality','Effectiveness','Effectiveness','Quality','Quality','Quality');
$unique = array_unique($main);
$count = array_fill_keys($unique, 1);//init all counts to 1
foreach($main as $key => $val)
{
    if ($count[$val])
    {//can be left out, if the unique array is produced by an array_unique call
        $main[$key] .= '_'.$count[$val];//append counter
        $count[$val]++;//increment count
    }
}
print_r($main);
```

That's it. You could use the `foreach` construct and iterate the main array by reference, too:

```
$count = array_fill_keys($unique, 0);//init to 0
foreach($main as &$val)
{
    $count[$val]++;//increment, before changing $val
    $val .= '_'.$count[$val];
}
```

Comment: works fine aswell.. :) thanks for the light you shed on the matter.
I would like to use the above approach as i learn php.

Answer (score 0):

below is your regular expression, i don't know why your using regular expression when this case you can simply concatenate the suffix to the string using the `.` operator.

```
$metric = preg_replace("/(.*)/","$1_$i",$metric);
```

Comment: i tried both the appending the suffix and using the preg_replace, but the values in the parent array main do not change..

if i push the values into another array in the `if($metric == $value){` block i will loose the order of the main array..

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want even without regular expressions. Here simple example:

```
$main = array('Quality', 'Effectiveness', 'Effectiveness', 'Quality', 'Quality', 'Quality');
$unique = array('Quality', 'Effectiveness');
foreach ($unique as $unique_value) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($main as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === $unique_value) {
            ++$counter;
            $main[$key] = $value . '_' . $counter;
        }
    }
}
unset($unique_value);
```

Comment: works perfectly.. thanks a lot :) :)

i used the preg_replace as i was hoping php would support the same feature as in perl...